# what is the reason befind putting questions' stat on left on questions list?

Tags: usability-study

Giving the fact that users read left to right, does SO want users to read question's stats first then question title ? if so why ? wouldn't be more pratical to read first the question's title ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left to right language with left aligned starting position makes the left end even (straight). This leads to a **(reading) flow when the stats are placed on the left side**.

If the stats are placed on the right end, the uneven sentence lengths can lead to a quite unstructured viewing experience.

Answer (score 0):

Users don't necessarily ready left to right. In the case of SO's list of questions, the user is going to scan the titles downwards; once you fixate on a question title, you can glance to the side to view the stats.

As for whether to put the stats on the left or right, because the question text is left-aligned it makes it neater to put the stats on the left where they are a consistent short distance away.